# Custom menu as subviews

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, addsubview

Im looking to build a custom menu which has 3 levels. The first level will expand as a subview when a menu icon is tapped, and will be exactly 1/3 of the superview width. Tapping on a menu item will expand a second menu level again at exactly 1/3 of the superview width. And you guessed it, tapping a menu item here will expand the third and final subview.

My question really is how best to handle this, in terms of architecture and the view hierarchy.

Each menu level will have its own view controller, and when adding a subview I'll just call `menulevelviewcontroller.view`.

I guess I'm just curious as to whether there is a better way of doing this that's more built for this kind of thing, or any suggestions at how others would approach this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you need only one `UIViewController` with three `UIView` subclasses (menu levels). This approach will help you to animate different menu levels and handle all menu events in one controller. This approach may helps you save a lot of time unlike more flexible and complicated solution.

Comment: But can I do this in Storyboard? I don't think I can add UIViews in Storyboard that aren't in a ViewController?

Comment: If you want to add finite count of levels, you can add needed cost of subviews and animate its showing.